# Is there json_build_object short form if props has same names?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to drop out 'id' and 'email' parts if object names is the same as column name?

```
SELECT pu.project_id, json_build_object('id', u.id, 'email', u.email) AS user
      FROM projects_users pu 
      LEFT JOIN users u ON pu.user_id = u.id 
      WHERE project_id=1
```

Something like:

```
SELECT pu.project_id, json_build_object (u.id, u.email) AS user
      FROM projects_users pu 
      LEFT JOIN users u ON pu.user_id = u.id 
      WHERE project_id=1
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but how to pick fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK getting all `users` column in the JSONB, you can use:

```
SELECT pu.project_id, to_jsonb(u) AS user
FROM projects_users pu 
  LEFT JOIN users u ON pu.user_id = u.id 
WHERE project_id=1
```

If you want to remove one or two keys from that, you could e.g. use `to_jsonb(u) - 'password_hash' - 'last_login'`

Alternatively use a derived table that only gets the columns you want:

```
SELECT pu.project_id, to_jsonb(u) AS user
FROM projects_users pu 
  LEFT JOIN (
    select id, email
    from users
  ) u ON pu.user_id = u.id 
WHERE project_id = 1
```